# Can't Install Runescape (Broken Packages?)

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

Here is my Terminal readout.

```
wublyfe@wublyfe-K53E:~$ sudo -s -- << EOF
> wget -O - https://content.runescape.com/downloads/ubuntu/runescape.gpg.key | apt-key add -
> mkdir -p /etc/apt/sources.list.d
> echo "deb https://content.runescape.com/downloads/ubuntu trusty non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescape.list
> apt-get update
> apt-get install -y runescape-launcher
> EOF
[sudo] password for wublyfe: 
--2016-12-24 16:07:34--  https://content.runescape.com/downloads/ubuntu/runescape.gpg.key
Resolving content.runescape.com (content.runescape.com)... 91.235.140.195, 91.235.140.194
Connecting to content.runescape.com (content.runescape.com)|91.235.140.195|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 942 [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                   100%[===================>]     942  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2016-12-24 16:07:34 (6.57 MB/s) - written to stdout [942/942]

OK
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]    
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Get:6 https://content.runescape.com/downloads/ubuntu trusty InRelease [2,236 B]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]  
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [68.2 kB]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [43.1 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [19.4 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [25.6 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [212 B]
Fetched 465 kB in 1s (435 kB/s)     
AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors.
Reading package lists... Done
W: https://content.runescape.com/downloads/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease: Signature by key AAC9264309E4D717441DB9527373B12CE03BEB4B uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 runescape-launcher : Depends: libglew1.10 (>= 1.10.0-3) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
wublyfe@wublyfe-K53E:~$
```

Comment: You should have been able to post the log without any modifications if you used the formatting option to paste code. libglew1.13 is available in 16.04, this dependency should have been resolved trough the virtual package, I hand no problem installing it on a 16.04 VM. Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install -f` that will try to fix broken dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Sorry that this response is a bit late, I just happened upon your question.

I notice from your other package sources that you are running Ubuntu Xenial Xerus.
It does not seem that Jagex has updated their package to Xenial yet, so you should start by logging in to their website and contacting [Runescape Customer Support](https://secure.runescape.com/m=ticketing/c=M7cTO6wUoKo/technical_support_2014?cat=89) and requesting that they update their package.  Ideally, they would have released an update to this package while 16.04 was in testing.
The dependency that the installer is looking for, **libglew1.10**, is not in the xenial repository.  It has been deprecated and replaced with **libglew1.13**.

If you are set on running Runescape before Jagex updates their package, you can install the deprecated libglew1.10 package from the trusty repository manually.  Try downloading the package for your architecture from [libglew1.10 page of the the Ubuntu Package Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libglew1.10). Once you have downloaded the package install it (replace with the actual path to the file):

```
sudo dpkg -i /package/path/name.deb
```

and then try installing the `runescape-launcher` package again.

```
sudo apt-get install runescape-launcher
```

I was able to get to character creation in the game with no issues.

We don't have the libglew1.10 package updated to xenial, so you will probably get a very annoying ldconfig response indicating that those libglew1.10.so files are not symbolic links to other locations as they should be.  While we could fix that, it could make it harder to remove the manually installed libglew1.10 package whenever Jagex releases a xenial-supporting package, so I chose to leave it.